# "can't open device COM5" on arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

This is what I get when I upload the program. I'm connecting the Bluetooth module to my Arduino UNO board.

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM5": The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.
>
> Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

Comment: What happens if you try uploading without the Bluetooth module connected to the Uno?

Answer (score 2):

User Peki on https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=302362.0 said to go to "Tools/Port" in the arduino menu. Select your port and you should be good to go. Worked for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same error many times and the solution for me was to reconnect the usb cable to the UNO.

You can also check if you have the correct port selected (COM5).

Answer (score 0):

The UNO only has 1 Tx/Rx pair. You'll have to power off or otherwise disconnect the the Bluetooth shield when programming the board because the Bluetooth shield is in control of Rx.

In other words you can't send data over the USB serial interface since the Bluetooth is in control. It's a pain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choice the correct **board type** you have connected and going to upload your program in.

as you are using `Arduino UNO` board, go to menu `Tools` -> `Board` and select **"Arduino/Genuino UNO"** board type, next select the port from `Tools` -> `Port` to the port it's connected to. Now you will successfully upload your program.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Found that I have another SW running which default connects to any COM port that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Arduino simulator then disconnect the simulator from Arduino by clicking on the Break icon then upload code to Arduino from Arduino IDE. Now after upload complete you can connect simulator with Arduino and uploaded code will work with simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Go to tools and check port and board. If they are correct then I am assuming you have connected RX and TX of Arduino.

As you are using a Bluetooth module so the RX and TX of your Arduino will be connected to the module. Before uploading the disconnect them and upload the code. After uploading and disconnecting the  USB connect the RX and TX again.
This has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

first check for correct port is chosen
next  this happend to me    check for power, sometimes when board don't get proper current (if you are using laptop at low power) attach charger to laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with my board because I can't upload my code ,then I also had my brothers arduino uno so connected his and tried to upload it uploaded successfully ,so I think this shows that there is some problem with the board and my settings but when I checked my settings they were correct

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).